# Remove suffix from actual file extension

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to use `Rename-Item` to remove trailing characters including the hyphen from a filename, ex. `123456.001.zip-4.22815.ren` to `123456-001.zip`.

```psh
Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name.split('-')[0])
```

seems to be something I am missing after the split.

Comment: where's the underscore?

Comment: I am sorry it is the dash not an underscore after the .zip

Answer (score 2):

The split operation must be performed in a scriptblock (`{}`). A simple expression (`()`) won't work.

```psh
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] }
```

Add `-replace '^(\d+)\.', '$1-'` if you want the period replaced with a hyphen.

```psh
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] -replace '^(\d+)\.', '$1-' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my script to work with these changes;

```
$src = "D:\temp"
Get-ChildItem -path $src -filter *.ren | ForEach-Object {    
 Rename-item -path $_.FullName -newname $_.Name.Split('-')[0]  }
```